# Are there really no ways to lock chrome profiles now?

Tags: google-chrome

Follow up to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1047080/is-it-still-possible-to-lock-or-password-protect-chrome-profiles). None of the solutions in that post work anymore. I'm wondering if anyone would know of any way to lock a chrome profile, either official or unofficial. This is isn't as important, but it would be great if the solution worked for both windows 10 and the latest Ubuntu.